# How to assign individual background colors for progress circles in RadialBarChart using Recharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, background, recharts

I am currently working on a data visualization project using React and the [Recharts](https://recharts.org/) library. I am utilizing the RadialBarChart component to display multiple progress circles, each representing a different dataset. Everything is working smoothly, and the progress circles are displaying correctly based on the data.

However, I am facing a challenge in customizing the appearance of the progress circles. I would like to set a distinct background color for each progress circle. The goal is to make each circle visually unique, giving it a specific color that matches its associated dataset.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  LabelList,
  PolarAngleAxis,
  RadialBar,
  RadialBarChart,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Tooltip,
} from 'recharts';

const CircularProgressGroup: React.FC<TCircularProgressGroupProps> = ({
  size,
  isDark,
  items,
  className,
}) => {
  /*
   items[]: {
     label: string;
     colorHex: string;
     value: number;
     maxValue: number;
     tooltip?: string | React.ReactNode;
     percentage: number;
     arrow: string;
     fill: string;
   } */

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer
      width={size}
      height={size}
      minWidth={size}
      className={className}
    >
      <RadialBarChart
        innerRadius={40}
        outerRadius={100}
        startAngle={270}
        endAngle={-90}
        barSize={16}
        data={items}
      >
        <RadialBar
          dataKey="percentage"
          cornerRadius={8}
          // TODO: I need to set background dynamically
          background={{
            fill: isDark
              ? '#f0f2ff'
              : '#f7f8fa',
          }}
          angleAxisId={0}
          minPointSize={1}
        >
          <LabelList
            position="insideEnd"
            dataKey="arrow"
            fill="#fff"
            fontSize={10}
          />
        </RadialBar>
        <PolarAngleAxis
          type="number"
          // 0 - 100 percentage
          domain={[0, 100]}
          angleAxisId={0}
          tick={false}
        />
        <Tooltip
          content={props => {
            if (props.active && props.payload && props.payload.length) {
              const payload = props.payload[0].payload;

              return (
                /* Custom code tooltip here */
                // ...
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </RadialBarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};
```

I tried rendering each `RadialBar` for each item that exists and thus I was able to customize the background color, however, the entire graphic is affected in its dimensions and I lose the ability to configure the `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` props.

I've also tried rendering each `Section` component inside the background prop and it doesn't seem to work *(`Section` is a `recharts` component)*.